# How to prevent a type from being declared as a by value parameter?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, pass-by-value

I have a class `T` and I want to make this code not compile:

```
void PassByValue(T);
```

but allow all of these:

```
void PassByRefernce(T&);
void PassByPointer(T*);
```

Note: that I want it to be illegal (i.e. generates a compile error) to **declare** a function taking a `T` by value even if the function is never used or defined.

---

Edit: Note that the following is totally valid C++:

```
class T {
  public:
    T() {}
  private:
    // Prevent copy/assignment
    T(const T&);
    T& operator=(const T&);
};

void Fn(T);  // I want this line to error, even if the function is never used.

int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get any better than deleting the copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not strictly possible (see below), the best you can do is make such function unusable/undefinable by making `T` uncopyable.

It is done by deleting the copy ctor, like this:

```
class T
{
    T(const T&) =delete;
    T& operator=(const T&) =delete;
    .....
};
```

If you cannot use C++11, the same effect happens making those declaration as private:

```
class T
{
public:
    .....
private:
    T(const T&);
    T& operator=(const T&);
};
```

No implementation is required.

In this way the class cannot receive a state from another instance, and hence the only way to pass to a function is by an indirection (via reference or pointer).

---

Of course this will not "solve" (literally) the original question, since declaration of things like

```
void func(T);
```

are still possible. However it will not be possible to call that function, and hence the safety of T is granted.

Unfortunately, for how the C++ language is today defined, no "clean" solution exist, since a code like

```
struct A;
void func(A);
```

must compile.

Although the code itself does nothing (it just declare some symbols) there is nothing in `struct A;` saying something about `A` semantics. To deny the declaration of `func` we must be inside the translation unit (CPP file) that contains or includes the full `A` declaration (so that we can know no copy is possible), that must - at that point - preceed the one of func. But this happens not necessarilly in all the translation units the above snippet is included.

There are languages that can do that: think of D, just to remain in the "system langages domain". But D -which allow a "use before fully declare"- doesn't "include sources" but "import modules" (the full definitions are accessible to the compiler) supporting iterative translation (if something is not yet defined and defined later the compiler goes back to "refine" and repeats until it "converges" to consistent code, or rejects the code if it finds inconsistencies). And -because of its "import mechanism"  and semantic/syntactic separation, cannot link to (most of) C++, but only accepts C compiled libraries or objs. (and require C to D translation of headers!)

Will C++ translation passes evolve towards a D-like one? Hard to be said. Very unlikely while the C backward compatibility of C "inclusion model" must be retained.

Comment: I already know of that trick but it doesn't do what I'm asking for, it's still legal to declare a function that takes a T by value (http://codepad.org/0hKyU3zw), you just can't use the function (http://codepad.org/yhApLTW6).

Comment: Well, you can always _declare_ a function taking T, by value or by whatever. You can declare a function as taking Ming the Merciless as an argument if you want to. But making the copy constructur inaccessible prevents you safely from _using_ the function.

Comment: @Damon: Actually the OP has a point: anticipate the error so that its effect are more controlled: If declaring doesn't work you know immediately you cannot do that. If declaring works, you first write 20+ functions, and than you discover you cannot use them!

Unfortunately for him, C++ declarations have as the only requirement the existence of the symbols they refer. The effective existence and reachability of the associated implementation are a separate and successive step. WHothout that limitation C-style modularisation (and forward declaration for recursive data) would not be possible.

Comment: Forward declarations would always break what I'm asking for, but I don't think that limitation is needed for recursive data structures if you are willing to require that the compiler be able to run the semantic passes over the code in other-than-lexical order (and that cleans up a LOT of other cruft as well).

Comment: @BCS: In theory you're right,and you can do even more avoiding the need to "declare before use". languages like D allow that. But D is not C++ compatible (you cannot import or link to a C++ exported function: this works only with the C/C++ common subset).

What you are asking is technically feasible, but requires to break some C compatibility that are still prerequisite.
It is however an issue that is in discussion and may be in further releases of the language may come.

In C and C++ a code like `struct A; void func(A a);` must compile.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include some of that, I'll 'accept' it.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options. either make the copy constructor private or make T abstract class.